# Why does my algorithm to rotate array right by k times without extra array running in O(n) work only for small arrays and not for big ones?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the ***Monk and Rotation*** problem given on HackerEarth ([here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/)) and I know other algorithms in the market that can do the work for me but I tried to make a new efficient algorithm for rotating array elements to the right by *k* times **without using another array and without using any custom library functions** and trying to run it in **O(n)**. So, I came up with my solution where I started with the first element of the array and used a *temp* variable to store the first element and then swap **temp** with the element that will come at the array index after the rotation and then again swapping with the next position after rotation for that particular element and so on... I stop when the **temp** variable equals the starting element of the given array.

**Note: I assume that all the elements are distinct**

But the problem is that it works for me in my local system and also passes the test cases mentioned on the HackerEarth Website but I am not able to pass the rest of the private test cases there.

---

Below is my code for your reference:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;
typedef pair<ll, ll> pll;
typedef pair<string, string> pss;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;
typedef vector<pii> vii;
typedef vector<ll> vl;
typedef vector<vl> vvl;

int main() {
    ll t, temp;
    cin >> t;    //inputing test cases
    while(t--){
        vl arr;
        ll i,n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){    //inputing array
            cin>>temp;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        }
        
        /*Main Algo*/
        ll temp1 = arr[0];
        temp = arr[0];
        while(1){
            i = (i+k)%(n);
            swap(arr[i], temp);
            //cout<<"temp: "<<temp<< endl;
            if(temp == temp1)break;
        }

        //Printing Rotated Array
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An example of the test case:

```
1 
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

My Output:

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't work if `(n % k) == 0`

Comment: Doesn't work when gcd(n, k) > 1. You need a completely different algorithm.

Comment: Actually I don't think, this is possible in O(n) without additional storage of at least O(k). Or you can do it in O(n*k) without any additional storage.

Comment: Who teaches `#include <bits/stdc++.h> ` and `typedef long long ll;`? That's an awful way of writing C++ code. [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68159325/1625187).

Comment: If you ever plan to write code for more than a hobby on competitive sites you'd do well to forget that `bits/stdc++.h` exists, delete all of those typedefs, and seriously consider if `using namespace std;` is worth the unexpected sadness it can cause.

Comment: @Evg and @RetiredNinja I get the point of not using that `bits/stdc++.h` header but can you please point out why shouldn't I use the `typedef's`? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516237/16570636) but couldn't get a reason to not use it here. I used it here to just avoid repetitive long initializations.

Comment: @RadientBrain Because such `typedef`s make your code much harder to read. Compilers don't care, but people do.

Comment: @derpirscher: there are various O(n) algorithms which use O(1) storage. A few years back, I did a brief survey of rotation algos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660916/1566221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why my custom made algorithm [...] works only for small arrays and not for big arrays?

Because it is not guaranteed that with repeated `i = (i+k)%n` increments you will visit all elements.

More specifically, this will only work when *n* and *k* have no common divisor (other than 1).

For instance, if *n* = 4 and *k* = 2, then the odd indices of your array will never be visited.