# Move first k elements of an array to the end

Tags: algorithm

**Task:** The rotation of the string *α* by *k* positions is the string *α[k:]α[:k]*, which is created by moving the first k characters to the end. For example, rotating "*abcdefghi*" by 4 is "*efghiabcd*".
Design an algorithm to calculate the rotation. The algorithm receives a string in an array, in the same array it should output. Furthermore, it only has O(1) memory available.

**Question:** I'm wondering if there is an algorithm faster than O(k*n).

Code of naive approach:

```
def move(arr, k):
    cur_k = 0
    while cur_k<k:
        i=0
        while i<len(arr)-1:
            temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[i+1]
            arr[i+1] = temp
            i+=1
        cur_k+=1
    return arr
```

Comment: Yes, there is. There are O(n) algorithms. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660916/1566221) (which is in C++, so not marked as duplicate, but it tries to explain the algorithm as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar use case some time ago, and I came up with the following solution (actually in the original code I used Python's slice assignment and tuple unpacking features, but I replaced them with a helper function to comply with the O(1) memory requirement).

We have 3 possibilities:

- `n == 2*k`: we simply need to swap the two `k`-items blocks
- `n < 2*k`: we can swap the first two `k`-items blocks; after that, the second block will already be in the right position, and we can loop to handle the remaining part
- `n > 2*k`: we can swap the first and last `n-k`- items blocks; once again, the last block will be in the right position, and we loop to handle the remaining part

This algorithm is O(n) in the worst case, O(k) in the best case (`n == 2*k`), and O(n-k) when `n` is a multiple of `k` greater than `2*k`

```
def swap_block(start, stop, delta, ls):
    for i in range(start, start+stop):
        ls[i], ls[i+delta] = ls[i+delta], ls[i]

def my_rotate(k,s):
    ls = [c for c in s]
    left = 0
    right = len(ls)
    span = right - left
    while span != 0:
        if span == 2*k:
            swap_block(left, k, k, ls)
            span = 0
        elif span > 2*k:
            swap_block(left, k, k, ls)
            left += k
            span -= k
        else:
            change = span - k
            swap_block(left, change, k, ls)
            left += change
            span -= change
            k -= change
    return ''.join(ls)

>>> for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, end=' => ')
    my_rotate(i, 'abcdefghij')

1 => 'bcdefghija'
2 => 'cdefghijab'
3 => 'defghijabc'
4 => 'efghijabcd'
5 => 'fghijabcde'
6 => 'ghijabcdef'
7 => 'hijabcdefg'
8 => 'ijabcdefgh'
9 => 'jabcdefghi'
```